# Как избавиться от кольца в БД?

Tags: база-данных

Допустим, таблица "Объект" (см. картинку) будет содержать разные объекты. Под объектом имеется в виду конкретный вариант из множества: гараж, квартира, дача.
У них имеются разные атрибуты: площадь, этаж, количество комнат - если это квартира; площадь участка, фундамент, туалет - если это дача.

Идея: вынести в таблицы - по причине имеющихся совершенно разных атрибутов у разных типов объекта (например, у гаража не будет атрибута "площадь кухни", "количество комнат", сколько соток, имеется ли баня в наличии, туалет и т.д.

Таким образом добавим к таблице "Объект" FK на "Тип" объекта. Таблица "Тип" связана связью многим-ко-многим с таблицей "Атрибуты". Так мы можем узнать какие атрибуты есть у конкретного объекта (иначе говоря - какие атрибуты разрешены для конкретного типа объекта).
Ну и таблица "Значение атрибута" ссылается как на объекты, так и на атрибуты и содержит значение конкретного атрибута какого-либо объекта (например, "Площадь: 40".

Как избавиться от круговой связи (кольца), чтобы при удалении записи не возникало ошибок?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где вы здесь кольцо увидели? вы стрелками связи нарисуйте и увидите, что проблемы нет. Т.е. если навесить FK и constraints, то при удалении, например, "типа" у вас автоматически удалится "объект", из-за этого удалится "значение атрибута". Далее - из-за удаления "типа" удалится так же и "соответствие между типом и атрибутом". Т.е. никаких проблем с удалением нет.

Comment: если такая структура вас смущает, можно сделать по-другому: для каждого "типа" сделать свою таблицу и хранить атрибуты там. Т.е. удаляется три таблицы (атрибут, его значение и связь с типом), но добавляются другие таблицы, которые друг на друга не ссылаются (есть ссылка только на таблицу "объект"). А в саму таблицу "объект" можно перенести общие для всех типов данные (например, цена, владелец, дата и т.д.) Т.е. вместо "кольца" получится простой граф

Answer (score 3):

У вас нет никакого кольца, всё совсем даже наоборот.

[image: Текущая ситуация]

Основная проблема вашей схемы в том, что AttrVal может содержать object.type и attr, которые не обязаны быть связаны в TypeAttrs.
*Грубо говоря, база не помешает вам указать "площадь огорода" для "квартиры".*

Решений мне известно три:

- Добавить валидацию в приложение, забив на то, что структура в базе сама по себе не обеспечивает целостности данных
- Добавить валидирующие триггеры на изменение(insert, update) в AttrVal
- Распространить конфликтующие ключи по таблицам, упаковав их в композитные первичные/уникальные ключи:

  [image: С композитами]

  В совокупности с двумя FK:
- AttrVal(object_id, type_id) -> Object
- AttrVal(attr_id, type_id) -> TypeAttrs

проблема становится решённой, потому что одно поле type_id фигурирует в обоих ключах.

Но с этим добром, если не база, то ORM не захочет нормально работать.

---

Связанные вопросы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533379/176064) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708496/176064)