# Проектирование БД: сетевые связи

Tags: база-данных

Всем добрый день.

Пример, разумеется, не очень реальный и чисто для того, чтобы о нем рассуждать.

Итак, много кто играл в танки онлайн, или любую другую игру, где у игрока есть несколько "персонажей", в нашем случае танков. При этом все танки имеют какую-то модель: у кого Т-34, у кого Тигр и так далее. У каждого танка куча базовых характеристик. На каждый танк можно поставить разные модули (не будем рассуждать о типах модулей, с ними ничего особо не изменится). Итак, модули: пушки разного калибра, гусеницы, башни разные и так далее. На каждый модуль тоже куча характеристик. Это две справочные таблицы.

Затем, каждый пользователь может купить себе танк и поставить на него разные модули - но, разумеется, только те, которые комплектуются с этим танком. Так мы получаем еще две таблицы, состоящие только из двух внешних ключей (ну и id для удобства).

[image: Схема полученной БД в IDEF1x]

Итого - цикл? Как поступить в этой ситуации? Не вижу варианта, в котором полученный пример можно представить иерархически, как учат в универе и как требуют в дипломе. Разумеется, у меня не танки, но случай похожий.

Какой нормальной форме соответствует этот случай?

Добавлено: проблема скорее в том, что я сомневаюсь, что это правильно.

Comment: Там нет цикла. Следуя **по** связям нельзя сделать круг.

Comment: @Кнопкатык , тем не менее, таблица Модуль танка пользователя нуждается в дополнительном контроле целостности. Я бы написала триггер, но правильно ли это?

Comment: Depends. Какие повреждения вы хотите этим предотвратить?

Comment: @Кнопкатык , чтобы пойдя по ключам вверх к Модулям и Танкам пользователя мы пришли далее к одной Модели танка.

Answer (score 3):

**Первичный ключ танка можно сделать частью первичного ключа его модулей**. Получится составной первичный ключ, да.

Этот приём называется "идентифицирующей связью" (от модуля к танку), когда **модель танка**, к которой подходит модуль, является его неотрывной характеристикой. Фактически ограничение внешнего ключа в модулях будет действовать везде, где есть ссылки на конкретные модули.

Если аналогично поступить с "танками пользователей" (включить в их первичный ключ **модель танка** и наложить на неё внешний ключ), то...

...можно наложить на "модули танков пользователей" **пересекающиеся внешние ключи**: одним сослаться на `(танк_пользователя, танк)`, а другим на `(модуль_танка, танк)`. Важно, чтобы при этом `танк` в каждом из этих ключей был **одной колонкой**, тогда разные значения в них будут невозможны.

Answer (score 0):

```
table user_tanks(
 id int,
 type int, -- ключ в справочник танков
 module_gun int, -- ключ в справочник модулей
 module_tracks int, -- ключ в справочник модулей
 module_radio int, -- ключ в справочник модулей
 ...
)
```

В справочнике танков забиты все те-же поля с модулями по умолчанию, если null, значит модуль не предусмотрен, если 0(0='none' в справочнике модулей) - значит предусмотрен, но по умолчанию не стоит

Comment: Это не избавляет нас от круга связей между таблицами.

Comment: @naiad09 это почему же?

Comment: @rjhby от Танков к Модулям, от Танков пользователя к танкам и Модулям.
К тому же, прошу предположить, что количество типов модулей неизвестно.

Comment: @naiad09 "от Танков к Модулям, от Танков пользователя к танкам и Модулям" и? Где круг то? Опять таки, из задачки "не будем рассуждать о типах модулей, с ними ничего особо не изменится"

Comment: @rjhby блин. типы модулей приемлемы только в такой постановке вопроса. поэтому пример получился у меня не очень...