# Как создать JoinTable с id типа не Integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Используя генераторы я создал 2 модели (и таблицы в БД):

```
rails g model Article name:string hunt_name:string body:text

rails g model Category name:string hunt_name:string
```

После чего в моделях я прописал следующее:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :hunt_name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end


class Article < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :hunt_name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Насколько я понимаю, `primary_key` указывает поле, по которому будет производиться поиск при вызове, например `Article.find(id)` (поправьте, если неправ). Кроме того в поле `id` данной таблицы будет содержаться уже не число (1, 2, 3...), а именно то, что находится в поле `hunt_name` (опять же, поправьте, если неправ).

После этих манипуляций я создал JoinTable:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableArticlesCategories articles categories
```

Но привязки статей к категориям не происходит по очевидной причине (узнал, посмотрев в скиму): поля в Join Table'е имеют тип `integer`, в то время как `hunt_name`, который, как мне кажется (см. выше) является `id` в своей таблице - типа `string`.

Отсюда вопрос: стоит ли вообще делать так, как я делаю (может быть стоит вообще отключить `id` в таблицах `articles` и `categories`)? Если это не противоречит Convention over Configuration, то как указать Join Table'у, что его поля должны иметь тип `string`? Или по-другому: как сохранить `id` в двух таблицах в числовом виде, но при этом оперировать данными, обращаясь к `hunt_name` (как будто бы это он `id`), и при этом всем не менять тип данных в Join Table'е? Что из этого лучше и как делать правильнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ох, с чего бы начать...*

```
self.primary_key = :hunt_name
```

#### Выкиньте это вообще и впредь не трогайте руками свойство `primary_key`.

Что является первичным ключом в таблице, указывается **в самой таблице**, прямо в БД, при её создании. То, что вы ORM даёте такую "вредную подсказку", расходящуюся со схемой БД, может привести к совершенно непредсказуемым последствиям.

---

Rails довольно навязчиво предлагает использовать т. н. "суррогатный первичный ключ", который заключается в искуственном сопоставлении каждой записи какого-то уникального и всегда существующего значения. Обычно реализуется автоинкрементом, реже случайными UUID, а бывает и иначе.

Вы же предполагаете, что в вашем случае *строковый* `hunt_name` тоже сгодится как первичный ключ. Может и так, я вашей предметной области не знаю, если это из неё следует, то это "натуральный первичный ключ". По меньшей мере убедитесь, что значения этого свойства сущности (= столбца таблицы) удовлетворяют следующему:

- Они **уникальны** среди всех записей (`UNIQUE` constraint)
- Они **есть у каждой** записи (`NOT NULL` constraint)

А ещё хорошо бы, чтобы они **никогда не менялись**, потому что первичный ключ таблицы указывает на канонический способ ссылаться на отдельные строки этой таблицы, т. е. значения этого ключа будут не только в самой таблице, но и во всём, что на неё ссылается. Если менять их, то везде. Если у вас в БД ещё при этом хорошо настроена поддержка ссылочной целостности (наложены строгие внешние ключи везде, где они правда есть), то БД вам ещё будет постоянно жаловаться, что изменяя значение первичного ключа вы нарушаете ссылочную целостность. Где-то можно временно ослабить требования (проверять целостность только при коммите), но не везде.

Сделать таблицу, которая имеет строковый первичный ключ можно такой миграцией:

```
create_table :things, id: false do |t|
  t.primary_key :key, :string
end
```

Если вам потребуются **составные** первичные ключи ([например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533414/181100)), ActiveRecord вообще расползётся по швам. Возьмите [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel), к примеру.

Оставлять же модель без первичного ключа вовсе плохая идея, т. к. ActiveRecord не сможет с объектами такой модели делать практически ничего, кроме чтения/инстанцирования.

---

А что касается соединительных таблиц — как можно было заключить из вышенаписанного, традиционно они содержат первичные ключи связываемых таблиц, но при этом собственного первичного ключа не имеют. Написать определение такой таблицы в миграции можно и самостоятельно, необязательно безвольно слушаться рельсогенератора. Избавиться от оков `has_and_belongs_to_many` можно, перейдя на `has_many :through` ([рекомендуется](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#has-many-through)) или с помощью [опций](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: Я немного запутался. Сначала вы говорите выкинуть "primary-key" вообще, а позже приводите пример с этим же "primary-key". Я правильно понимаю, что вы дико не рекомендуете переопределять pk в МОДЕЛИ, но предлагаете это сделать при описании миграции?  
Еще насчет миграции: опцию `id` вы отключили потому, что при ее наличии она автоматически станет первичным ключом? И еще. Ваша строчка в миграции, создающая pk не равна такой? `t.string :key, index: {unique: true}`. Потому что при такой созданной таблице у меня нормально отрабатывают и хелперы и все остальное вроде поисковых по таблице методов.

Comment: Нет, вообще ответ на свой вопрос я получил и он меня устраивает, благодарю. Просто хочется с деталями разобраться, потому что как обычно: ответят на 1 вопрос, появляется еще 10.

Comment: И еще один вопрос есть. Если теперь первичным ключом в одной таблице является строковое `hunt_name`, а в другой - строковое `name`, то как должны выглядеть поля в JoinTable? `t.string: article_hunt_name` и `t.string: tag_name` или как и без изменения первичного ключа `t.string :article_id` и `t.string tag_id`?

Comment: @smellyshovel первичный ключ определяется в БД и только в БД, ActiveRecord сам спросит у БД, где первичный ключ. Дополнительно указывать ключ в модели в лучшем случае бесполезно. Часть ответов есть в [документации к `create_table`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table). Нет, первичный ключ имеет чуть более весомый статус, чем unique+not-null. Необходимые названия полей можно и методом тыка установить, по сообщениям об ошибках.

Comment: Я, в общем-то, так и сделал. Установил методом тыка. В итоге получились поля, заканчивающиеся на id в JoinTable. Только почему оно так - все равно не понимаю, ведь этих полей - Id - даже нет в соединяемых таблицах

Comment: @smellyshovel уверены, что нет? Как проверяли?

Comment: получал запись в Rails console и смотрел какие поля приходят в ответ. Ещё в dbconsole смотрел.

Comment: @smellyshovel интересно. И ассоциация работает? Если да. то это по меньшей мере странно и стоит перейти на has_many :through, назвав поля так, чтобы в них был смысл.

Comment: Вообще я думаю, что в рельсах все подстроено именно под Id. Поэтому в jointable ссылаюсь на id полей, но на самом деле подразумевается первичный ключ

Comment: вообще гайды гласят, что has many through имеет смысл использовать только в том случае, если с этим jointable придется работать как с отдельной моделью. А я такой необходимости не вижу.

Comment: @smellyshovel к сожалению, это "подразумевается" это очередной неявный кусок логики, который из названий совершенно не следует. Вы только что встретились с ситуацией, когда путь к однородному коду и путь Rails ведут в разные стороны. И просто слушаться гайдов уже недостаточно, надо начинать думать своей головой.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59069/discussion-between-smellyshovel-and-d-side).