# Структура базы данных с циклом(ромбом)

Tags: база-данных, структуры

Есть 2 пары таблиц.

Некий справочник:

- A (id)
- A_Component(id, a_id)

И произвольная выборка из этого справочника:

- B (id, a_id)
- B_component(id, b_id, ac_id)

[image: UML]

Очевидно, что эта структура замыкается в ромб, где средствами базы не обеспечивается целостность данных - ничто не заставляет поля `B.a_id` и `A_Component.a_id` совпадать, а хотелось бы.

Ещё раз: *необходимо, чтобы `B_C.b_id` и `B_C.ac_id` указывали на одну и ту же сущность `A`.*

Вижу пару возможных решений:

- исключить таблицу `B`, тем самым разорвав ромб зависимостей.
  решение не подходит, потому что в `B` есть ещё данные, относящиеся ко всей выборке целиком
- набор триггеров/ограничений, которые будут валидировать корректность данных в создаваемом `B_Component`.
  этот метод порождает пару запросов в базу для валидации.

Существует ли более каноничный/элегантный способ для подобной структуры?

Comment: Разве что в A_C и B вместо суррогатного ключа использовать какой нибудь реальный, составной, включающий в себя a_id и ссылаться на них соответственно так же набором полей. но решение так себе

Comment: И иногда решения подкидывает реальный мир под который строится схема, но по данной абстракции таких решений не найдется

Comment: *предположим, что это A(пицца), A_C(топпинги, применимые к этой пицце), B(пицца в заказе), B_C(топпинги пиццы в заказе).* В этом случае у Вас вообще ошибочная схема данных, объединяющая шаблон создания экземпляра сущности и созданный экземпляр - связи A-B и A_C-B_C не существуют, их следует удалить.

Comment: @Akina видимо ТС хочет проконтролировать на уровне БД, что добавить в заказ можно только ингредиенты из шаблона

Comment: @Mike *ТС хочет проконтролировать на уровне БД, что добавить в заказ можно только ингредиенты из шаблона* Да пусть контролирует... хотя куда как разумнее просто организовать процессы так, чтобы не было возможности внесения в экземпляр заказа нешаблонизированных экземпляров ингредиентов. Но в любом случае связывать готовую пиццу и рецепт на неё - нельзя.

Comment: Убрать эти связи - вполне себе решение, однако придётся клонировать кучу данных из A/A_C в B/B_C. Денормализация, все дела... Неприятие этой связи также не вполне понятно. Вполне себе ***прототипное наследование***. Допустим, пицца эта ещё не готова, а лишь заказана. И оперативное изменение этой заказанной пиццы при изменении шаблона для нас плюс(допустим :) ). Другое дело оплаченная готовая пицца - там можно всё сериализовать и хранить в камне. *Напомню, пицца - первый пришедший в голову пример подобного справочника*

Comment: @vp_arth Akina имел ввиду, что если вы сохраняете связь с шаблоном, то шаблон вы больше никогда в жизни не поменяете. Например вы перестали закупать шпинат и вам надо убрать его из шаблонов. А уже ранее были заказы в которые он был включен. Если связи в БД жесткие то вы не сможете удалить его из шаблонов

Comment: Это очевидно, да. В контексте задачи не принципиально. Пусть, шаблоны иммутабельны - новый рецепт - новый шаблон.

Comment: @D-side, составные первичные ключи? В этом что-то есть) Спасибо

Comment: @vp_arth Я про составные первичные ключи написал первым же комментом. вы почему то не прореагировали, думал не устроило ибо минусы в этом то же есть, не всегда можно найти адекватный ключ

Comment: @Mike, нет, скорее не понял, о каких ключах речь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

> Очевидно, что эта структура замыкается в ромб, где средствами базы не обеспечивается целостность данных - ничто не заставляет поля B.a_id и A_Component.a_id совпадать.

Это ошибочное утверждение. Чтобы оно было правильным, необходимо, чтобы было обеспечено соответствие значений B.a_id и A_Component.a_id (т.е. эти таблицы должны быть связаны между собой).

При отсутствии такого соответствия у Вас имеются две независимые цепочки линейной связи, а в схеме должны присутствовать две копии таблицы А - одна из них связана с B, другая с A_Component.

Comment: Ок. Вероятно, терминологически я где-то неправ. Но каким образом ваш ответ решает проблему? "чтобы было обеспечено соответствие значений" - в этом и вопрос. Как?